# MacOS X: Remove plist file when the app is removed

Tags: macos

I am showing a license form at app startup, but it should be shown only at the first time the app launched. Not always. So, i tried to store a flag in plist or user defaults, but upon the app removing(move to trash), plist or userdefaults is not getting removed from system, thus i'm not able to achieve my task.

This is what i have been trying below,

I am storing a flag in plist file and save the file(in Documents directory) during App launch, so next time , i can read from there and find out whether the app is running first time or not. I am failing here, because even the app is removed(move to trash) from system, i am not able to remove this plist file.

I tried to set a flag in NSUserDefaults too, but after deleting the app and build again and launch the app, it still persists the previous value i stored. I am wondering, NSUserDefaults doesn't get deleted when app is deleted from system?

```
NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];        
    [ud setObject:@"1" forKey:@"APPLAUNCHED"]; // store user default
    [ud synchronize];
```

Could someone please advise?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither user defaults nor the application sandbox get automatically removed when the application is deleted. I think there's no way to do that.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. I am seeing user defaults is NOT getting removed after deleting(Moved to trash) the binary. Thus i'm not able show the license form, when i build the app again and try to launch the app.

Comment: Exactly. This is intended behavior. Users who delete your app and then re-install it, have their preferences and documents intact. As a side effect, they don't have to fill the license form once again. I think it's end users' responsibility to delete unused files and sandboxes if they are obsessed about disk space usage.

Comment: But, it should be like, we have to show license at first time app startup. How can i fix this? How can i remove user default or plist when the app is moved to trash? Any help or suggestion please.

Comment: If you need to show license after the app got updated, you can store the current app version in `NSUserDefaults` and compare it with the actual app version to decide whether to show it. If the app is simply deleted and re-installed (without being updated) there's no way to tell if it was deleted after the previous launch.

Comment: Could you tell how can ask user to inform to delete user defaults from Mac Lion machine? I can atleast add this in release notes.

Comment: Traditionally, user defaults are saved in a file named as the app bundle identifier with the `plist` extension in ~/Library/Preferences/. The sandboxes are in ~/Library/Containers/, also named after app bundle identifiers. To go to the Library folder click the Go menu in the Finder, press Option and select Library.

Comment: OK, unfortunately my app plist with bundle identifier no where saved in my Lion machine.

Comment: Hi, I fixed this issue by checking app creation date using Carbon APIs.