# OS X Lion: How to store persistent data under Application folder

Tags: osx-lion

I need to store a persistent data for my Mac application. I'm able to store this data in a plist or `NSUserdefaults`. But I want to store this persistent data in my application folder, so that when I delete the app (move to trash) from the Mac, this persistent data also will get deleted. I want this to work like that. What would be best approach to do this and how can I store persistent data in my app folder, so that the data also gets deleted when the app is deleted?

```
NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];        
[ud setObject:@"1" forKey:@"APPLAUNCHED"]; // store user default
[ud synchronize];
```

Comment: This won't work - you can't guarantee that you will have write permission to /Applications

Comment: And another reason not to do this - someone re-installing or upgrading the app will trash their persistent data.

Comment: Yes the requirement is we should not store user's persistent data once the app is removed. Because, we need to show an EULA form at app startup every fresh launch. And, i'm wondering how that is impossible to store a data persistently and gets removed when the app is deleted. Coredata doesn't help for me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MacOS X: Remove plist file when the app is removed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365445/macos-x-remove-plist-file-when-the-app-is-removed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good practice to store persistent data in the applications folder. You should use the
Home or Application Support Directory depending on the type of content you want to store

The following describes the Mac Application guidelines

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/AppRuntime/AppRuntime.html

Comment: Hi all, My requirement is this, not storing persistent data. I can store whatever the way it is, but it should get removed when the app is deleted from Mac machine. That's the reason why, i was trying to say can i store data in app folder, so that it will get deleted when the app is removed. Besides all, please suggest me, this is what i need, i want to store a single flag persistently somewhere, but this persistent data should be removed once the app is deleted from the system. Please suggest me.

Comment: Another way to look at this would be to delete previous app data when installing the app. you could write a preinstall script or a postinstall script to achieve this. PackageManager would provide this feature

Comment: Hi, Thank you..Looking into some simple solution. Can't we register for some notification when app is getting deleted? Is there any notification like this? Can't i store this persistent flag in Application bundle resource? (or) Anything else can be handled simply?

Comment: I dont think so. Most people handle it in post install and pre install scripts

Comment: OK, thank you very much. Could you share me some tutorials for pre and post install methods? Its just an .app binary i have now for Mac.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/PackageMakerUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: OK, also i am setting a flag in NSUserDefaults in my mac app. I thought i can see this bundle identifier plist file in ~Library/Preferences folder and i can delete that manually for testing. But, unfortunately i'm not seeing any of my app plist file there. Could you give me an advise how can i delete manually the NSUserdefault set by my Map app?

Comment: It might be in your .app bundle

Comment: No, if it is in bundle, it should be have been removed when i delete the app and all my problems would have been solved now.

Comment: Hi, I fixed this issue by checking app creation date using Carbon APIs.